# Storing value in a multidimensional array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is the quickest way to store a value in an array at position, let's say, [30][1][0] ...

I tried `var myArray[30][1][0] = new Date();` but it won't work without doing `var myArray = []; myArray[30] = []; myArray[30][1] = [];`  beforehand.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  My issue is that I don't know, first, if the variable myArray already exists and, second, if there's already a value at position, let's say, [29][2][15], which I wouldn't want to overwrite.

Comment: why are you trying to assign a date to a multidimensional array?

Comment: Short answer: Because I'm managing hundreds of dates on a NodeJs back-end that need to be sent as JSON to the front-end and then back to the NodeJS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do what you want would be:

```
var array = [[[new Date()]]];
```

However, the resulting multidimensional array will not have exactly 30 elements on the third dimension and 1 on the second, like you had in your original code. Not sure if that's going to be a problem for you.

When you do `myArray[30][1][0]`, JavaScript is trying to access element 30 in the array `myArray`, but, since `myArray` variable was not initialized to anything yet, it has the value `undefined`. So your code is equivalent with:

```
var myArray;
myArray[30] = new Date();
```

This code is going to issue the error `Cannot set property '30' of undefined`.

Edit:
If you want to make sure the array exists before assigning values and avoid overriding existing values, the most elegant way I can think of is:

```
// Store a value in the array, at index (posX, posY, posZ), only if
// that position in the array is currently empty
function storeDateNoOverride(theArray, posX, posY, posZ, date) {
    var theArray = theArray || [];
    theArray[posX] = theArray[posX] || [];
    theArray[posX][posY] = theArray[posX][posY] || [];
    theArray[posX][posY][posZ] = theArray[posX][posY][posZ] || date;
}

// If variable theArray doesn't have a value yet, assign it to a new array
var theArray = theArray || [];

storeDateNoOverride(theArray, 30, 1, 0, new Date());
```

Comment: No, it's not a problem, but my issue is that I don't know, first, if the variable array already exists and, second, if there's already a value at position, let's say, [29][2][15], which I wouldn't want to overwrite.

Comment: @Emilio: Please see my edit (added sample code that checks for existing values)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is amazing!

Comment: Assuming a hard-wired depth of three does not seem to fit the definition of "elegant".

Answer (score 0):

> What is the quickest way to store a value in an array at position, let's say, [30][1][0] ...

The classic way is

```
array[30] = array[30] || [];
array[30][1] = array[30][1] || [];
array[30][1][0] = array[30][1][0] || [];
array[30][1][0].push(value);
```

or the equivalent in suitably parameterized fashion.

You could make a little helper:

```
function subarray(array, n) {
  return array[n] = array[n] || [];
}
```

Then you could write

```
subarray(subarray(subarray(array, 30), 1), 0).push(value)
```

You could also write the helper to do all the accessing and checking in one fell swoop:

```
function getNestedElement(array, firstIndex, ...indices) {
  if (firstIndex === undefined) return array;
  return getNestedElement(array[firstIndex] = array[firstIndex] || [], ...indices);
}
```

And then write

```
getNestedElement(array, 30, 1, 0).push(value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Will consider!

Answer (score -1):

You can not initialize a nested object like that. There are two ways. If you know your ND array size in advance you should first instantiate it as follows;

```js
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e);
};
function arrayND(...n){
  return n.reduceRight((p,c) => c = (new Array(c)).fill().map(e => Array.isArray(p) ? p.clone() : p ));
}

var arr = arrayND(5,5,5,void 0); // create 5x5x5 array and fill each cell with "undefined"
arr[3][2][1] = arr[3][2][1] || new Date(); // if falsey value then insert current date.
console.log(arr);
```

However if you don't know the multidimensional size in advance and would like to grow your array dynamically you can use a function like `getNestedValue()` and `setNestedValue()`. In this particular case i will extend the `Object.prototype`. In production code this should be done through `Object.defineProperty()` tool though.

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};

Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                       : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                         this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
               : this[a[0]] = a[1];
  return this;
};

var arr = [];
arr.getNestedValue(30,1,0) || arr.setNestedValue(30,1,0,new Date()); // if exists don't overwrite it;
console.log(arr[30][1][0]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Will consider!